# Beginner CRUD Console Application

Tags: c#, sql, console, asp.net, sqlite

I wrote this basic CRUD app + simple report so I could practice talking to a db directly. I purposefully avoided repository pattern and Entity Framework and only used a library to show the coming data a bit more readable.

Having that in mind, I'd love to get some feedback, particularly in regards to bad practices that I should avoid in my professional career as developer. You can be brutal, I take criticism well. :)

I'll post just the code for my controller and the rest in this link to my repo:

Here's the link to my repo. https://github.com/cappuccinocodes/CodeTracker1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using ConsoleTableExt;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations;

namespace CodeTracker1
{
    internal static class CodingController
    {
        static readonly string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ConnectionString");
        internal static void GetUserCommand()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nMAIN MENU");
            Console.WriteLine("\nWhat would you like to do?");
            Console.WriteLine("\nType 0 to Close Application.");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 1 to View All Records.");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 2 to Insert Records.");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 3 to Delete Records.");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 4 to Update Records.");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 5 to Generate Reports.");

            string commandInput = Console.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandInput)) {
                Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid Command. Please choose an option\n");
                GetUserCommand();
            }

            int command = Convert.ToInt32(commandInput);

            switch (command)
            {
                case 0:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Get();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Post();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Delete();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Update();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Reports.GetReportCommand();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid Command. Please type a number from 0 to 5.\n");
                    GetUserCommand();
                    break;
            }
        }

        internal static void Post()
        {
            long date = GetDateInput();
            long duration = GetDurationInput();

            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var tableCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                tableCmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO coding (date, duration) VALUES ({date}, {duration})";
                tableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }

            string inputDate = new DateTime(date).ToString("dd-MM-yy");
            string inputDuration = new DateTime(duration).ToString("HH:mm");

            Console.WriteLine($"\n\nYour time was logged. Date: {inputDate}; Duration: {inputDuration}.\n\n");

            GetUserCommand();
        }

        internal static void Delete()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease type the Id of the record would like to delete. Type 0 to return to main menu.\n\n");

            string commandInput = Console.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandInput))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou have to type an Id.\n");
                Delete();
            }

            var Id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (Id == 0) GetUserCommand();
          
            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var tableCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                tableCmd.CommandText = $"DELETE from coding WHERE Id = '{Id}'";
                int rowCount = tableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                while (rowCount == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\n\nRecord with Id {Id} doesn't exist. Try Again or type 0 to return to main menu. \n\n");
                    Id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (Id == 0) GetUserCommand();

                    if (rowCount != 0) break;
                }
            }
            GetUserCommand();
        }

        internal static void Get()
        {
            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var tableCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                tableCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM coding";

                List<Coding> tableData = new List<Coding>();

                SqliteDataReader reader = tableCmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        tableData.Add(
                        new Coding
                        {
                            Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                            Date = new DateTime(reader.GetInt64(1)).ToShortDateString(),
                            Duration = new TimeSpan(reader.GetInt64(2)).ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nNo rows found.\n\n");
                }
                reader.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("\n\n");

                ConsoleTableBuilder
                    .From(tableData)
                    .ExportAndWriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n");

                GetUserCommand();
            }
        }

        internal static void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease type Id of the record would like to update. Type 0 to return to main manu.\n\n");

            string commandInput = Console.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandInput))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou have to type an Id.\n");
                Update();
            }

            var Id = Int32.Parse(commandInput);

            if (Id == 0) GetUserCommand();

            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                var checkCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                checkCmd.CommandText = $"SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM coding WHERE Id = {Id})";
                int checkQuery = Convert.ToInt32(checkCmd.ExecuteScalar());

                if (checkQuery == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\n\nRecord with Id {Id} doesn't exist.\n\n");
                    GetUserCommand();
                }

                long date = GetDateInput();
                long duration = GetDurationInput();

                var tableCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                tableCmd.CommandText = $"UPDATE coding SET date = {date}, duration = {duration} WHERE Id = {Id}";
                tableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string inputDate = new DateTime(date).ToString("dd-MM-yy");
                string inputDuration = new DateTime(duration).ToString("HH:mm");

                Console.WriteLine($"\n\nYour time was logged: date({inputDate}), duration({inputDuration}).\n\n");
                connection.Close();
            }

            GetUserCommand();
        }

        internal static long GetDateInput()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease insert the date: (Format: dd-mm-yy). Type 0 to return to main manu.\n\n");
            DateTime result;

            string dateInput = Console.ReadLine();

            if (dateInput == "0") GetUserCommand();

            bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateInput, "dd-MM-yy", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out result);

            if (success)
            {
                var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateInput, "dd-MM-yy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
                long date = parsedDate.Ticks;
                return date;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nNot a valid date. Please insert the date with the format: dd-mm-yy.\n\n");
            return GetDateInput();
        }

        internal static long GetDurationInput()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease insert the duration: (Format: hh:mm). Type 0 to return to main manu.\n\n");
            TimeSpan timeSpan;

            string durationInput = Console.ReadLine(); 

            if (durationInput == "0") GetUserCommand();
       
            bool success = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(durationInput, "h\\:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out timeSpan);

            if (success)
            {
                var parsedDuration = TimeSpan.Parse(durationInput);
                long date = parsedDuration.Ticks;
                if (date < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nNegative Time Not allowed.\n\n");
                    GetDurationInput();
                }
                return date;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nNot a valid time.\n\n");
            return GetDurationInput();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My advice: use Dapper instead of ADO.NET: https://dapper-tutorial.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very neat, and I see that you tried to take care of the basics like disposing of the connection. My main concern is the recursive call to `GetUserCommand`.

**Do not use recursion where you could have a simple loop!**

I would suggest that you change `GetUserCommand` to the following:

```
internal static void GetUserCommand()
{
    bool closeApp = false;
    while (closeApp == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nMAIN MENU");
        Console.WriteLine("\nWhat would you like to do?");
        Console.WriteLine("\nType 0 to Close Application.");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 1 to View All Records.");
        // ...
        Console.WriteLine("Type 5 to Generate Reports.");

        string commandInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandInput))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid Command. Please choose an option\n");
            continue;
        }

        int command = Convert.ToInt32(commandInput);
        switch (command)
        {
            case 0:
                closeApp = true;
                break;
            case 1:
                Get();
                break;
            // ...
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid Command. Please type a number from 0 to 5.\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In `Get()` you have a ticking time bomb:

```
internal static void Get()
{
    using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        ...
        GetUserCommand();
    }
}
```

This sort of thing has spoiled many good programmers' weekends/sanity. Here you never dispose of the connection and can eventually either run out of stack space or database handles / resources.

Comment: @BCdotWEB, That is correct, the problem in `Get()` is the recursive call to `GetUserCommand` before `using (var connection…` is out of the scope.

Comment: @BCdotWEB, see what happens in this example: [TIO](https://tio.run/##jZLbasJAEIbv9ylGryKixFtDC9JaKERarNDrdTOVgWQ37K5pQ/HZ081BcxDbzu38880/B2FmwoiiOBqSB3jLjcUkYEzE3BjY5A9KShSWlIQlPD@SSZXh@xjZNwMX6XEfk@jpvEmVqfNlqBRlmzbTaXBJ0Qd4gzTcw8KfXBQtpgynMyrG@bsmiyFJ9MZPq90qhPV2@7Jdwk4pSLjMq54gWupoNJ4EPdRaZqSVTFDa@fqLrOd3BCf2S8dN3iGD0MgtRmf8iXX3kimKoF4aXu3lT3RUF0Zd64NtzWb9tpoy5waM5da1J2mHBXAHfsBO5wO/anXQPGmu2ZRVrndorFcCYsww/of3sNQ5/BimTU3run4uL@O6nM@JJH7C4Gtu3bwyUgEdeHF1pGbyrvUNp@svrDD@5UqurCh@AA)

Comment: In this example [TIO](https://tio.run/##hZFbS8NAEIXf91dM@5QQUtLXBoWiEYQWJQZ83q5jGUh2w@42GiS/PeZSc1NwHkLgzPl25owwvjCiri@G5BleSmMxCxkTKTcGjuWdkhKFJSVhB4/3ZHJl@ClF9sWgqfxySknM@hy3U3q9LZWjHGXjeeEg0Ts4CxluYRu4Q8eIaavpMyrFzasmiweS6Kwf9sn@AFEcP8U7SJSCjMuyexPESF2t1m44Q0WyIK1khtJuok@yTjBpqFj/ne5YKHqDPgD8b0ffD2cETQW3CMZy25BI2qUBbiAIWfWT@7NWZ82za8hXWzdAgsY6LSDFAtPlGP0RnYLrdvkGKvFjcZy/oq2Gvw7focGDrTvbYjrGkdPvQ3fmYDA1trr@Bg), the connection object is disposed of properly, but the unchecked recursive call still leads to a stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! I'll have a closer look.

Comment: Holy ghost! You have just changed my life. Haha. I finally understand the importance of while loops 